# I have implemented two for loops using a single while loop. It's time complexity should be O(n) or O(n2). Would it bypass O(n) constraint in question?

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, while-loop

In different coding competitions, there is a constraint of O(n). So, I thought of implementing using a **single while loop that works as nested for loop**. Would I be able to bypass the constraint or not in competitive coding platforms.
Code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i=0, j=0, n;
    cin>>n;

    while(i<n && j<n){
        cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;

        if(j==n-1){
            ++i;
            j=0;
        }
        else{
            j++;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great - you re-discovered *one while-loop is enough*. Try a few examples of `n` and gauge the output.

Comment: There is no such thing as *O(N2).* Do you mean *O(N^2)*?

Comment: complexity only care about the number of actions the computer does, not how you tell the computer to do them.

Comment: @user207421: linear search in an array of size n2 will take time O(n2).

Comment: Are you able to explain the meaning of O(n) ?

Comment: Try a recursive call, so that you can avoid the `while` and further reduce the complexity to O(1).

Comment: Abraham Lincoln liked the riddle: "How many legs does a dog have if you call his tail a leg?" (answer: 4).

Answer (score 2):

You can also say that your algorithm runs in constant-time *O(1)* with respect to

`n = the number of coffee cups drunk by Stackoverflow users`.

As the number of coffee cups grows, your code still takes the same time to run. This is a perfectly correct statement.

However, those constraints you talk of specify a maximum time-complexity with respect to some given, or understood, variable *n*. Usually the size of the input to your program, again measured in some way that is either explicitly given or implicitly understood. So no, re-defining the variables won't get you around the constraints.

That said, writing a nested loop as a single loop, such as in the way you discovered, is not useless as there are situations where it might come in handy. But no, it will not improve your asymptotic complexity. Ultimately, you need to count the total number of operations, or measure the actual time, for various inputs, and this is what will give you your time complexity. In your case, it's *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* with respect to the value of *n* given to your code.

Comment: @PaulHankin I didn't say it's O(#coffees drunk), I said it's O(1) with respect to #coffees drunk. Would you not agree?

Comment: @PaulHankin Well it's like saying indexed access of an array is *O(1)* with respect to the length of the array, *n*. Yes, that implies that it does not asymptotically depend on *n*, and it's quite standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine complexity by counting loop depth.  Your code is still O(n<sup>2</sup>) (where n is the given value n), because j will be modified n<sup>2</sup> times, and in fact it will even print out n<sup>2</sup> lines.

To determine complexity, you need to count operations.  A lot of times, when you see two nested loops, they will both do O(n) iterations, and O(n<sup>2</sup>) time will result, but *that is a hint only*, not a universal truth.